# 動作の完成を表す言葉について、

Tags: grammar, words, usage, expressions

この質問は[こちら](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/whats-the-difference-between-%E5%B0%BD%E3%81%8F%E3%81%99-and-%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%9F%E3%81%99)からの追加質問です。

日本語を勉強し始めた頃から、たくさんの文章を読んだり動画を見たりしまして、若干の動作の終わりを表現する語を知ってますが、その使い分け、特に、日本人が脳内で感じれる単語の違いは分かりません。

例えば、水などの液体を全て飲んだら、いくつかの表現があります：

- 飲み切った
- 飲み果たした
- 飲み尽くした
- 飲んでしまった
- 飲み終わった

他の動詞も同じように活用できそうです：

- 売り切った
- 売り果たした（売ることが責任として売上を完成した感じみたいです）
- 売り尽くした（底の底まで商品を売り出した、本当に何も残ってない感じみたいです）
- 売ってしまった
- 売り終わった（今日の営業は終わったという感じみたいです）

その中、どれが一番慣用で、どれが間違い、そして、正しい選択肢が複数であれば、それらの違いは何かはわからないです。一般的なルールが何だとも知らないです。教えていただければ嬉しいです。

Comment: 「飲む」に関しては「飲み干す」も

Comment: 「～てしまう」は違う意味で、[「そのつもりではないのに、～する」という意味です](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/99508)。例えば、「間違って、新品のお皿を売ってしまう」（そのお皿は売らないつもりだったのに、売る）

Comment: FYI https://www.lang.nagoya-u.ac.jp/bugai/kokugen/nichigen/issue/pdf/10/10-03.pdf

Comment: 個人的には「売り終わる」はおかしいと感じます（製品の販売終了(discontinued)という意味では「終売した」とかですかね）。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 「尽くす」は種類や数がたくさんあってその全部を網羅した、という場合に使われます。coverage や exhaustiveness を表現する動詞だと考えるとよいと思います。一方で、「切る」は同様の状況でも使えますが、単純に分量が大きい1種類のものに対して使うことが多く、また時間や労力をかけたというニュアンスが伴います。典型的には以下のように使い分けます。

  - 店にある全種類の酒を飲み尽くした。
  - 1リットルのオレンジジュースを飲み切った。
  - 棚にある100冊以上の本を半年かけて読み尽くした。
  - 1000ページの長編小説を読み切った。
  - 閉店セールで店にある全商品を売り尽くした。
  - 新商品をたった30分で売り切った。
  - 日本中の高速道路をオートバイで走り尽くした。
  - マラソンで42.195キロを走り切った。
  - その問題に関して気付いた点はメールで言い尽くした。
  - 言いにくい話だったが、最後まで言い切った。
- 「飲み果たす」「売り果たす」とは言いません。単純に間違いです。「完売を果たす」などと言うことはできますが、この場合の「果たす」は "achieve" という意味です。
- 「飲み終わる」は量の多さや努力の有無とは無関係に使われる、ニュートラルな表現です。コップ1杯の水に対して「飲み切る」とは普通言いませんが、「飲み終わる」は使うことができます。
- 「飲んでしまう」は、文脈によって、後悔・不適切・不可逆・決意などといった特別なニュアンスが入ります。よくご存じでしょうから例だけ挙げておきます。

  - (後悔) 隣の人のドリンクを間違って飲んでしまった。
  - (不可逆) この薬を飲むと不老不死になりますが、飲んでしまうと元には戻れません。
  - (決意) 今日は気分がいいので、高いワインだけど飲んでしまおう。

Comment: 最後の「飲んでしまう」については[こちら](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/99508)をご参照くされば納得いくかと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございました。やはり確かめれない時は「XXし果たす」や「XXし終わる」と言う表現を避けた方がいいかもしれません。普段に「し切る」と「し尽くす」だけを使うと足りると思います。

Comment: @dvx2718 そうではなく、分からない時は「～終わる」の方が一番一般的で無難な選択肢かと思います。

Comment: @GuiImamura そうですか。分かりました。ありがとうございます。